# MUMPS - The MPI_Comm_f2c() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

I need to use MUMPS in my project. I wanted to test the installation with the simple example of solving equations (below). The problem is, that this code works correctly in my personal PC, but it gives me this error every time I try to run it in my work computer:

```
*** The MPI_Comm_f2c() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
[espreso-ws:3263] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

I've tried to look for possible solutions, but I've found only these questions:

[error: The MPI_Send() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772300/error-the-mpi-send-function-was-called-before-mpi-init-was-invoked)

http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2012/05/19262.php

None of them provides any solution.

So now, I'm incredibly confused about this and I don't really know, what should I try to do. There IS `MPI_Init()` invoked before `MPI_Comm_f2c()` of course.

Do you know, how to solve this problem?

---

#### mumps_solve.c

```
/*
 *  file c_example.c
 *  This file is part of MUMPS 4.10.0
 *  To run: aprun -n 2 ./dsimpletest < input_simpletest_real
 */
/* Example program using the C interface to the
 * double real arithmetic version of MUMPS, dmumps_c.
 * We solve the system A x = RHS
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <dmumps_c.h>
#define JOB_INIT -1
#define JOB_END -2
#define USE_COMM_WORLD -987654

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  DMUMPS_STRUC_C id;
  int n = 2;
  int nz = 4;
  int irn[] = {1,1,2,2};
  int jcn[] = {1,2,1,2};
  double a[4];
  double rhs[2];

  int myid, ierr;
  ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

  /* Define A and rhs */
  rhs[0]=5.0;rhs[1]=2.0;
  a[0]=3.0;a[1]=2.0;a[2]=1.0;a[3]=4.0;

  /* Initialize a MUMPS instance. Use MPI_COMM_WORLD */
  id.job=JOB_INIT;id.par=1; id.sym=0;id.comm_fortran=USE_COMM_WORLD;

  dmumps_c(&id); // here the program crashes

  /* Define the problem on the host */
  if (myid == 0) {
    id.n = n; id.nz =nz; id.irn=irn; id.jcn=jcn;
    id.a = a; id.rhs = rhs;
  }
#define ICNTL(I) icntl[(I)-1] /* macro s.t. indices match documentation */
/* No outputs */
  id.ICNTL(1)=-1; id.ICNTL(2)=-1; id.ICNTL(3)=-1; id.ICNTL(4)=0;
/* Call the MUMPS package. */
  id.job=6;
  dmumps_c(&id);
  id.job=JOB_END; dmumps_c(&id); /* Terminate instance */
  if (myid == 0) {
    printf("Solution is : (%8.2f  %8.2f)\n", rhs[0],rhs[1]);
  }
  ierr = MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

---

#### Makefile

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL=all

BINARIES=mumps_solve

.PHONY=all
all: mumps_solve

mumps_solve: mumps_solve.o
        mpicc mumps_solve.o -o mumps_solve -ldmumps

mumps_solve.o: mumps_solve.c
        mpicc -c mumps_solve.c -o mumps_solve.o

.PHONY=clean
clean:
        rm -f ${BINARIES} *.o
```

Comment: I notice that you're ignoring the return value from `MPI_Init`. How do you know if it's actually succeeding?

Comment: Depends whether you set MPI errors to be fatal. If not, you must check the return value.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I've tried it - it's ok.

Otherwise it looks, that the problem is caused by conflicting versions of MPI. I'll know better next week.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be hidden in the linking. I see that the actual call which raises the error is in a library against which you are linking.

In short: you maybe linked against multiple copies of MPI. One is initialized, one is not. The latter is called by your library and raises an error.

Solution in short: compile both the external library and your own code again, verifying that all compilation is done by the exact same physical copy of `mpicc`.

The library could be compiled and linked against a different copy of your MPI distribution than the copy against which you link your main library. If that is the case, there are multiple copies of the global variable which keeps track of the initialization state of MPI. Your call to `MPI_Init()` goes to the MPI copy which you linked against by invoking `mpicc` in your Makefile (located at `which mpicc`). If you call `MPI_Initialized(int*)` after `MPI_Init()`, you should find that it returns true.

If you had the chance to modify the source of the external library (mumps), and call `MPI_Initialized(int*)` just before the line that crashes, you should find that it returns false, even though you called `MPI_Init()`. This is a hint that the library and your binary are linked against different copies of your MPI distribution.

In my case (after two days of bumping my head against the wall), it was even a matter of different dynamically linked versions of MPI. I had the luck to be in control of the compilation of the library, and could hence modify the version of MPI it links against.